# How to convert R expressions to LaTeX/TeX without using a CAS?

Tags: r, latex, tex

I would like to be able to convert R expressions (ex. `1/2*x^2`) or formulas into a character string that contains the LaTeX (ex. `"\frac{1}{2} \times x^{2}"` - or something similar). I know that `expression()` can be used for something similar, generating mathematical notation in figures, but I'm not sure how to convert a similar type of expression into LaTeX. I want to be able to include this into a Sweave document.

Please give an example (like with the `1/2*x^2`), instead of just saying "use the `tikzDevice` package". It sounds like the `Hmisc` package might be able to do what I want, but I haven't figured out how yet.

I'm wanting to avoid using a CAS (computer algebra system), because I want it not have to rely on a complex external application, like that Ryacas uses, and want it to be able to run quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`latexTranslate` provides valid LaTeX output from string input but only partial expansion. The translation of x/y will not be converted to the prefix version, \frac {1} {2}.

```
require(Hmisc)
latexTranslate("1/2*x^2")
#[1] "1/2*x$^{2}$"
```